# Using hexes for AES decryption in python?

Tags: python, encryption, hex, aes

Part of an assignment is finding from a list of hex, the hex that responds to your secret key (made with sha256 and your id).

This is just the main applicable snippet of my code where `908a62b065abd3da8d92f1225600ed2e78a2a471a2395829afe89fffb7aef21f` is the *hex digest* that I will use as my key, and `EBBB632DA3240F6277C20830D6774213` is one of the texts I'm testing (EMDs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/72p4V.jpg, my key should be decoding one).

[image: EMDs]

I've tried each one, and none has worked. I feel that because of the modifications I make while passing, is most likely where my mistake is?

I'm just not sure how *variable type* affects the decryption? If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here or has pointers about AES decryption in `Python`, I would be incredibly grateful, thank you.

```
key = binascii.unhexlify('908a62b065abd3da8d92f1225600ed2e78a2a471a2395829afe89fffb7aef21f')
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

def decrypt(ciphertext):
    tempText = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext).decode('latin-1')
    l = tempText.count('{')
    return tempText[:len(tempText)-l]

print(decrypt(binascii.unhexlify('EBBB632DA3240F6277C20830D6774213')))
```

Comment: Where’s the assignment from?

Comment: Usually a new AES object should be used for each decryption process, but if you're using ECB that's not important. Your padding scheme is a little strange, but that shouldn't affect the results either (unless there are lots of `{` characters in the plaintext). Other than that your code looks ok.